# Subprocess result through shell instead of being saved into text file

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a Python script for my thesis research, and I'm having problems with the subprocess module.

What the script does is executing "perf" with lots of args (here is a simplified version):

```
cmd = 'sudo perf stat -C %s -I %s -x , -e "%s"' % (core_perf, interval, perf_event_text)
```

Then I split cmd into args, to have tokens to send to subprocess:

```
final_cmd = cmd.split()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.Popen(final_cmd, stdout=outfile)
```

The problem is that this works well, but the output is shown through shell and not saved into file.

If I do it for "ls", it works like a charm:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=outfile)
```

Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using shlex.split for splitting your command line? `import shlex` then `final_cmd = shlex.split(cmd)`

Comment: I think it may be because of the sudo command which spawns another shell. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied.

Comment: Just tried both! Neither worked :( Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perf stat` doesn't use `stdout` for its output but `stderr`, many programs starting a command and reporting on it (e.g. `time`) do the same to not clobber the output of the executed command.

So in this case, instead of `stdout=outfile` use `stderr=outfile`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info! It solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

another option is to pass the `-o` parameter to `perf` so it writes stderr output to the file you specify:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = shlex.split('perf stat -o outfile.txt ls')
subprocess.call(cmd)
```